# Object is not abstract and does not implement abstract member public abstract fun error in flutter with kotlin native code

Tags: java, android, flutter, kotlin

I'm trying to call a native kotlin code inside my flutter application .. am doing it this way

**flutter side**

```dart
class NativeLocationServices {
  static const currentLocationChannel = MethodChannel("com.deliveryrunner.driver/getCurrentLocation");

  getCurrentNativeLocation() async {
      // Either the permission was already granted before or the user just granted it.
      final arguments = {"test":"it is working"};
      final  currentLocation = await currentLocationChannel.invokeMethod("currentLocation",arguments);
      print(currentLocation);

    }
  }
```

**kotlin side**

```kotlin
package xxxxxx > here are my package name 

import android.content.*
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import androidx.annotation.NonNull
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel
import android.content.Intent
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import android.location.Location

class MainActivity : FlutterActivity() {
    private val LOCATION_CHANNEL = "com.deliveryrunner.driver/getCurrentLocation";
    private lateinit var channel: MethodChannel
    private lateinit var fusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this)
        MethodChannel(flutterView, CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler {
                call, result ->
            if (call.method == "currentLocation") {
                val arguments = call.arguments() as Map<String, String>
                val test = arguments["test"]
                fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
                fusedLocationClient.lastLocation
                    .addOnSuccessListener { location: Location? ->
                        // Got last known location. In some rare situations this can be null.
//                        result.success(location)
                        result.success("got the loation")
                    }
            }
        }
    }
```

but I am getting this error when I try to run the app

```
e: D:\Flutter\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\workmanager-0.4.1\android\src\main\kotlin\be\tramckrijte\workmanager\BackgroundWorker.kt: (132, 21): Object is not abstract and does not implement abstract member public abstract fun error(p0: String, p1: String?, p2: Any?): Unit defined in io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel.Result
e: D:\Flutter\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\workmanager-0.4.1\android\src\main\kotlin\be\tramckrijte\workmanager\BackgroundWorker.kt: (137, 25): 'error' overrides nothing

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':workmanager:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 14s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```